# How to fix automated access to this page was denied using nightmare.js

Tags: web-crawler, nightmare

I am **scraping** a site using `nightmare.js` , when I  goto url I get error:

> "Unfortunately, automated access to this page was denied."

```
await nightmare
      .goto(url)
      .wait(10*1000)
      .useragent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36');
   
   
html = await nightmare
       .evaluate(() => {
            return document.body.innerHTML;
        })
        .end()
        .then((html: any) => {
            return html;
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            throws(error.toString);
        });
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ not scrapping

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by this code.

```
   await nightmare.useragent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36')
        .goto(url);
```